# Method of Undetermined Coefficients where $g(t)$ is a product of functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ive been having some problems determining the process for finding a particular solution when $g(x)$ is a product of functions

For example, I dont understand why the initial guess for the particular soluion when $g(x) = x-3t^{-t}$ would be $Ae^{-x}$ + $Bt^2e^{-x}$

I understand you kinda wanna break it into parts:
for the $t$ part, i figured: $(Ax+b)$
for the $e$ part, i figured: $Ce^{-x}$
Therefore, we want our particular sol to = $Ce^{-x}(Ax + b) = e^{-x}(Ax + b)$

but when i plug it in,i do not get the right answer. I know there are a few similar questions out there but i am not sure where the flaw in my logic is...Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Like Amzoti hinted to, sometimes in your homogeneous solution you already have a term with the form of your first guess for the particular so you have to make it linearly independent, usually by multiplying by the independent variable.